# How to fix sub-ring menus cannot clicked when hovering in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an issue about some sub-ring menus in custom wordpress theme cannot clicked when hovering with the mouse such as screenshot below:

[image: cannot clicked]

**Here style.css**

```
.ringMenu:hover ul li.bottom {
  bottom: -180px;
  left: -90px;
  background: url(img/fanart.png) no-repeat scroll left/ 95% 80%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ringMenu:hover ul li.bottom a { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 95%;
  line-height: 27.0;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.ringMenu:hover ul li.bottom a:hover { 
  color: #ccc;
}

/* Right Ring */

.ringMenu:hover ul li.right {
  bottom: -180px;
  left:40px;
  width: 90%; 
  background: url(img/community.png) no-repeat scroll left/95% 80%;
  z-index: -1;  
}

.ringMenu:hover ul li.right a { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 99%;   
  line-height: 27.0;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  font-weight: 700;   
}

.ringMenu:hover ul li.right a:hover { 
  color: #ccc;
}
```

For further detail please check out [on this link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/). How I can fix it?

Thanks before

Comment: you should fix your images and positioning

Comment: Omg, the menu is horrible :S Use something more... normal. And modern :\ Plus the images take years to load even on very fast connection. Just, use something better and more user friendly.

Comment: @RRR How I can fix it?

Comment: @dingo_d I knew but its based request from my client

Comment: Advise your client that no one will want to visit his site if it looks like the design of the site hasn't changed from 1999. And use [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) to reduce the size of your images.

Comment: @user3077416 whole positioning is messed up its not easy to fix it... kindly let me know from where did you get the css for ring menu